# How convert Stream[IO, Int] to ZStream with cats-interop

Tags: scala, zio, cats-effect

I'm not a cats effect programmer, I have just started to learn ZIO. So I want use zio.ZStream to manipulate data of fs2 stream.
How I can convert Stream[IO, Int] to ZStream with cats-interop?

```
  import zio.stream.ZStream
  import zio.stream.interop.fs2z._
  import cats.implicits._
  import zio.interop.catz.core._
  import zio.interop.catz._
  val a: Stream[IO, Int] = ???
  val b: Stream[Pure, Int] = ???
  val zstream: ZStream[Any, Throwable, Int] = b.toZStream() // compile
  a.toZStream() // error ==> value toZStream is not a member of fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,Int]
```

Comment: It seems you first need to convert the **fs2** `Stream` into a `Stream[ZIO, A]` first, before being able to convert it into a `ZStream`

Answer (score 0):

To convert an fs2 `Stream[IO, Int]` to `ZStream[Any, Throwable, Int]` actually takes 2 steps:

1. Translate the effect type used by the original fs2 stream to ZIO. For that you can use the `translate` method which accepts an instance of `FunctionK`. I haven't found such an instance in the `zio/interop-cats` project so I think you have to define your own.

```scala
fs2Stream
      .translate(new FunctionK[IO, Task] {
        override def apply[A](fa: IO[A]): Task[A] = fa.to[Task]
      })
```

2. Translate the resulting fs2 stream into `ZStream` by using `toZStream()` function as you have already done.

Here's a full working example in which I create an fs2 stream, convert it to ZStream and then run it:

```scala
import cats.arrow.FunctionK
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream
import zio.{App, ExitCode, Task, URIO, ZIO}
import zio.interop.catz.*
import zio.stream.ZStream
import zio.stream.interop.fs2z.*

object Test extends App{
  
  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = {

    val fs2Stream: Stream[IO, Int] = Stream.eval(IO.delay(42))
    val zstream: ZStream[Any, Throwable, Int] = fs2Stream
      .translate(new FunctionK[IO, Task] {
        override def apply[A](fa: IO[A]): Task[A] = fa.to[Task]
      })
      .toZStream()

    zstream.foreach(a => ZIO(println(a))).exitCode

  }

}
```

Comment: I use the last version of interop-cat ivy"dev.zio::zio-interop-cats:3.3.0-RC1", and I get the error `could not find implicit value for parameter F: cats.effect.LiftIO[zio.Task]` for `fa.to[Task]`. How I can convert IO to Task?